# Limit of recurring series with arctan

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Let $a_{n+1} = \arctan (a_n)$. Find $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty } \, a_n$ if $a_1$ is chosen arbitrarily. 
I think the answer is 0, but I don't really know how to prove that. Could you give me some hints, please? 

Unfortunately, I don't know anything about derivatives yet

Comment: It may help to use the fact that the absolute value of the derivative of $\arctan$ is bounded by $1$.

Comment: Hint 1: there is only one solution to $x=\arctan x$. Hint 2: $\arctan x$ is always between $x$ and zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, I see, I'll try developing that, thank you!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you so much, I tried it and it worked! Have a lovely day :)

Comment: Good! Now, write it up and post it as an answer --- that's encouraged on this site. Then, later, you can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we know $|\arctan(x)| \le |x|$. Then
\begin{align}
\left|a_{n+1}\right| & = \left|\arctan(a_n)\right| \\
& \le \left|a_n\right|.
\end{align}
This shows that the sequence $\{|a_n|\}$ is non-increasing. Since it is bounded below by $0$, it converges. Let $A$ be the limit of $|a_n|$. We know $A \ge 0$. Take the limit in the first equality above to get
$$
A = \arctan A.
$$
Since the graphs of $y = x$ and $y = \arctan x$ have only one intersection at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$, $A = 0$.

**Addendum:**

To prove that $f(x) = x - \arctan x$ has only one root at $x = 0$, you kind of need to know about derivatives. First, check that $f(0) = 0$, so $x = 0$ is indeed one root. Next, compute $f'(x) = 1 - \frac 1{1 + x^2} > 0$ for all $x$. This means $f$ is strictly increasing, so there can be no other roots.

Comment: You meant $f'>0$ and then $f$ is stricly increasing, I think.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what got into me, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Though not rigorous  but this graphical interpretation of the problem gives us a fair idea that the point $a_n$ tends to {$0,0$}.

The single straight line is the graph $y=x$ and the curve represents $y=tan^{-1}x$.

The graph indicates a series of lines parallel and perpendicular to the x-axis.
where $A=a_1$,
and $C, E, G, I, K, M$ are $a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6$ respectively.

[image]